# Root Level TRACE Causes Endless Loop and Error, But INFO Level Doesn't in Logback

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, logback, trace

I'm facing an issue with Logback where setting the root level to TRACE appears to cause an endless loop and results in the following error:

```
2023-10-23 14:27:54.673+02:00 [DEBUG] Service ID: [] RequestIDs: [] com.couchbase.config - [com.couchbase.config][BucketOpenRetriedEvent][1000us] Failed to open bucket ["bucketName"] {"coreId":"0x349ec42600000001"}
com.couchbase.client.core.error.ConfigException: Seed Node NodeIdentifier{address=couchbase, managerPort=8091} is disconnected, bailing out.
    at com.couchbase.client.core.config.loader.BaseBucketLoader.lambda$ensureServiceConnected$6(BaseBucketLoader.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replayNormal(FluxReplay.java:877)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replay(FluxReplay.java:965)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyReplayProcessor$ReplayInner.request(SinkManyReplayProcessor.java:576)
    ...
    2023-10-23 14:27:54.673+02:00 [DEBUG] Service ID: [] RequestIDs: [] com.couchbase.config - ---> Repeat
```

However, when I set the root level to INFO, I don't encounter this issue. Could someone help me understand why setting the root level to TRACE triggers this behavior?

Here's my Logback configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- Define log properties -->
    <property name="SERVICE_NAME" value="Service" />
    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="logs/" />
    <property name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10MB" />
    <property name="MAX_HISTORY" value="7" />
    <property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX} [%-5level] ${SERVICE_NAME} id: [%X{id}] RequestIDs: [%X{requestIDs}] %logger - %msg%n" />

    <!-- Console Appender -->
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Error Log File Appender -->
    <appender name="ERROR_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_error.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_error.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!-- Warn Log File Appender -->
    <appender name="WARN_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_warn.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_warn.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!-- Debug Log File Appender -->
    <appender name="DEBUG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_debug.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_debug.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!-- Info Log File Appender -->
    <appender name="INFO_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_info.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_info.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!-- Fatal Log File Appender -->
    <appender name="FATAL_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_fatal.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>FATAL</level>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_fatal.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!-- Trace Log File Appender -->
    <appender name="TRACE_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_trace.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${

LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}_trace.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!-- Root Logger Configuration -->
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR_FILE" level="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="WARN_FILE" level="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE" level="debug" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="INFO_FILE" level="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="FATAL_FILE" level="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="TRACE_FILE" level="trace" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

It would be great if someone could shed some light on why changing the root level has this effect. Is there something specific to the TRACE level that might be causing this behavior?

We have an integration test that generates an error. The error goes into an infinite loop, which I have to terminate via the Task Manager when I set the root level to 'Trace.' However, if I set my root level to, for example, 'Info,' a regular error message is displayed, and the application terminates normally without entering an infinite loop. The integration test has been fixed, so the infinite loop no longer occurs. However, my logback should not create an infinite loop that renders the software non-operational when such an error is encountered.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Excellent use of ChatGPT to properly format your question (I think), but you didn't have to copy the first line of its response.

Comment: That's a DEBUG level log, so you see it when your log level is TRACE, but not when it's INFO (levels are TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL)

Comment: Does your program behave differently other than the log output?

Comment: We have an integration test that generates an error. The error goes into an infinite loop, which I have to terminate via the Task Manager when I set the root level to 'Trace.' However, if I set my root level to, for example, 'Info,' a regular error message is displayed, and the application terminates normally without entering an infinite loop.

The integration test has been fixed, so the infinite loop no longer occurs. However, my logback should not create an infinite loop that renders the software non-operational when such an error is encountered.

Comment: Can you take two or thread thread dumps during the infinite loop and share them? They should help to identify the cause.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the message is not logged at INFO. Only DEBUG and TRACE.

The couchbase cluster tries to connect until it is shutdown, so it's not quite infinite.  The issue appears to be that in your environment, the couchbase SDK cannot connect to the server. The waitUntilReady method in the SDK gives more information as to why the SDK cannot connect.